# Stuck on Django project tutorial I'm doing on Udemy - OperationalError at /admin/jobs/job/add/ no such table: main.auth_user__old

Tags: python, django, sqlite, anaconda, spyder

I am doing a Django tutorial I bought off Udemy. It's titled "Django 2.2 & Python | The Ultimate Web Development Bootcamp", in case some of you know this tutorial by instructor Nick (something, forgot last name). I'm using Django 2.0.2, exactly what was asked in the tutorial. SQLite3 database version 3.27.2, using up-to-date version of Spyder with Anaconda prompt, I'm on Windows 10 Pro, latest versions of "virtualenv" and "pip" as well.
So on the tutorial, I had to sign into the admin page and create an app called "jobs", with a jobs.models.py class called "Job". It adds this to the admin UI and then click on it and add (using "+" icon at top right) a "Job", which is adding an ImageField and a CharField that gets added. I get an error on the django admin page when I click "Save". The name of my project is "portfolio-project", sub-folders include "portfolio","blog", and "jobs".

I went back and re-did all the steps up to that point in the tutorial, and did it "to the letter". I've researched many questions for that error and can't find anything that works. I tried makemigrations, then migrate. It's possible it's a bug with the latest Django and SQLite, but not sure.

> ./portfolio-project/jobs/models.py
>   '''

```
from django.db import models

# Create your models here.
class Job(models.Model):
    image = models.ImageField(upload_to='images/')
    summary = models.CharField(max_length=200)
```

'''

> ./portfolio-project/jobs/admin.py
>   '''

```
from django.contrib import admin
from .models import Job


admin.site.register(Job)
```

'''

> ./portfolio-project/portfolio/settings.py
>   '''
>   """

```
Django settings for portfolio project.

Generated by 'django-admin startproject' using Django 2.0.2.

For more information on this file, see
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/topics/settings/

For the full list of settings and their values, see
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/settings/
"""

import os

# Build paths inside the project like this: os.path.join(BASE_DIR, ...)
BASE_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__)))


# Quick-start development settings - unsuitable for production
# See https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/howto/deployment/checklist/

# SECURITY WARNING: keep the secret key used in production secret!
SECRET_KEY = 'qe=d*&syck0@rb6y6lo2f$+*mp=9p4m5zr6o^10+wb-%ti$w!g'

# SECURITY WARNING: don't run with debug turned on in production!
DEBUG = True

ALLOWED_HOSTS = []


# Application definition

INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'jobs.apps.JobsConfig',
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
]

MIDDLEWARE = [
    'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
]

ROOT_URLCONF = 'portfolio.urls'

TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS': [],
        'APP_DIRS': True,
        'OPTIONS': {
            'context_processors': [
                'django.template.context_processors.debug',
                'django.template.context_processors.request',
                'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
                'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
            ],
        },
    },
]

WSGI_APPLICATION = 'portfolio.wsgi.application'


# Database
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/settings/#databases

DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.sqlite3',
        'NAME': os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'db.sqlite3'),
    }
}


# Password validation
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/settings/#auth-password-validators

AUTH_PASSWORD_VALIDATORS = [
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.UserAttributeSimilarityValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.MinimumLengthValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.CommonPasswordValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.NumericPasswordValidator',
    },
]


# Internationalization
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/topics/i18n/

LANGUAGE_CODE = 'en-us'

TIME_ZONE = 'UTC'

USE_I18N = True

USE_L10N = True

USE_TZ = True


# Static files (CSS, JavaScript, Images)
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/howto/static-files/

STATIC_URL = '/static/'

# added this for the project...not here by default
MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'media')
# added this for the project...not here by default
MEDIA_URL = '/media/'
```

'''

I expect the admin page to say I "saved" the "Job", and instead I get this error:
'''

```
OperationalError at /admin/jobs/job/add/
no such table: main.auth_user__old
Request Method: POST
Request URL:    http://127.0.0.1:8000/admin/jobs/job/add/
Django Version: 2.0.2
Exception Type: OperationalError
Exception Value:    
no such table: main.auth_user__old
Exception Location: C:\Users\John\myenv\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\sqlite3\base.py in execute, line 303
Python Executable:  C:\Users\John\myenv\Scripts\python.exe
Python Version: 3.7.3
Python Path:    
['C:\\Users\\John\\portfolio-project',
 'C:\\Users\\John\\myenv\\Scripts\\python37.zip',
 'C:\\Users\\John\\myenv\\DLLs',
 'C:\\Users\\John\\myenv\\lib',
 'C:\\Users\\John\\myenv\\Scripts',
 'C:\\Users\\John\\Anaconda3\\Lib',
 'C:\\Users\\John\\Anaconda3\\DLLs',
 'C:\\Users\\John\\myenv',
 'C:\\Users\\John\\myenv\\lib\\site-packages']
Server time:    Fri, 6 Sep 2019 19:13:44 +0000
```

'''

Comment: The error is clear: `no such table: main.auth_user__old`. Try running `migrate` or `makemigrations` and then `migrate`.

Comment: I'll do it again and let you know what happens.

Comment: I ran "python manage.py makemigrations" and I got "no changes detected". Then I ran "python manage.py migrate" and got "No migrations to apply."

Comment: I would try to drop the db and re-create it. then run makemigrations and migrate.

Comment: I don't know how to drop sqlite db. I was hoping to solve this without ten hours studying database commands, Django documentation, and trying other questions with the same error (and then it causes an error and I have to re-start the project, very likely have the same exact issue, then go and study for hours and hours again, having no answer....I've been through this sooooo many times, and that happens often. I know people can't just give the answer and make me study and think, I just really need a reasonable solution that doesn't take more than 2 hours to figure out)

Comment: Just delete the file and it will be automatically re-created. You probably re-named some table.

Comment: By the way, I just wanted to let everyone know that I'm new to web development. I tried last summer (2018) and spent 40+ hours and couldn't get past django-admin login after creating first "superuser" account. Web development is a "mine field" filled with errors galore, with almost never a simple solution. I will study and think about the error. I just don't want to be stuck on it for 20+ hours and four days. That's all.

Comment: okay, I will try that, thanks man

Comment: I deleted the sqlite3.db, then re-made it with makemigrations and migrate. Nothing changed. Then, I deleted the project and re-did it. Now I can't even get into the django-admin page, no matter how many superuser accounts I make.

Comment: It's Django 2.0.2 bug with Sqlite3.

Answer (score 0):

I've faced such problem before it's bug that came with how Django 2.0.2 work with Sqlite3 best work around this is to update Django to the latest version, or use postgresql database.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

`git add -A 
 git commit -m
 python manage.py makemigrations
 python manage.py migrate`